# Spring boot - 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have my api in Spring Boot.

I have 2 classes:

Here is my Supplier Class:

```
 public class Supplier{
     @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
     private List<Product> products;      <---  This one is working perfectly fine.

     @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
     private List<Ingredient> components;      <---- this is the line where I am getting an error

}
```

Here is the error message that I am getting:

> 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'Ingredient'

Here is my Ingredient class

```
public class Ingredient {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private String unit;
     private Double quantity = 0.0;
     private Double cost = 0.0;
     private Double price = 0.0;
}
```

**My Question:**
What is a possible fix to the above error in:

```
private List<Ingredient> components;
```

Even though the line above it is working ?

Comment: Assuming `Supplier` is also an Entity, so can you please tell which column in `Ingredient` Entity defines this association with `Supplier` Entity. You'll need to use that column name with an additional Annotation `@JoinColumn(name = "<foreignKey>")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a unidirectional association `@OneToMany` you need to replace

```
@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Ingredient> components;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})  
@JoinColumn(name="components")
private List<Ingredient> components;
```

If you want a bidirectional association `@OneToMany` you have to add in your `Ingredient` class

```
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Supplier supplier;
```

and the supplier class nothing changes
links to help you understand

https://javabydeveloper.com/one-many-unidirectional-association/

https://javabydeveloper.com/one-to-many-bidirectional-association/

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: `@JoinColumn(name="components")` this tell Hibernate that there is a `components` Foreign Key column in the 'ingredients' table that defines this association, whereas the from the `Ingredient` Entity, there is no such column

Comment: @Haridarshan thanks for the clarification , is it the problem from not specifying the name of class with the assosiation ```@OneToMany(targetEntity = Ingredient.class)```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are annotating your type class which in your case is Ingredient. It should be annotated with @Entity .. Missing to annotate your class is one of the reasons to produce this error.